# App crashes when I try to edit an EditText view

Tags: android

I am trying to get my first app running on Android studio. The app instantiates and runs the setOnClickListener.

When I try to enter input for the addTextChangeListener it crashes.

"I have stripped back the code, to find where the fault is, but I still can't figure it out. I am new at this, being my first app.

```
outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);

        EditText ageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userAge);
        ageText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                int age = Integer.parseInt(userAge.getText().toString());
                int intYears = Integer.valueOf(userYears.toString());
                String text;

                if (age < intYears/3){
                    text = getString(R.string.Message_1, userAge);
                    outputText.setText(text);
                }
                else{
                    text = getString(R.string.Message_2, userAge);
                    outputText.setText(text);
                }
            }
        });
```

Expected: Enter an int m, convert int m to another int m' display m'.
          Enter int n in another text field, compare int n and m and display a text.

Result: Executes first part, app crashes when I try and enter int n in the other text field.

Comment: Please attach your log details

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed getText().

`int intYears = Integer.valueOf(userYears.getText().toString());`

Comment: Also, this part: text = getString(R.string.Message_1, userAge); it should be age instead of userAge, userAge is your textView, and you want to put the age to the string

Comment: I forgot getText().

I tried ```text = getString(R.string.Message_1, age)``` first, cos it seems natural to me as well. 
The IDE throws error ```suspicious argument type for formatting argument #1 in Message_1:conversion is s, received int(argument #2 in method call)```